# python encoding from str to unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding

i' ve a very simply environment:

```
In [64]: aa = '\xe1'

In [65]: aa
Out[65]: '\xe1'

In [66]: type(aa)
Out[66]: str

In [67]: u'\xe1'
Out[67]: u'\xe1'

In [68]: u'%s' % aa
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc
in <module>()
----> 1 u'%s' % aa

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

All I'd like to do is to convert this **aa** string to unicode. How could i do this?

In the db i've unicode strings, and with str i can' t make a resulting django query if it contains special characters. Using **.encode('utf-8')** or **unicode(aa)** i got the same **UnicodeDecodeError**.

I also tried playing with `sys.setdefaultencoding`, and then it might work, however it kills everything else.

Python version: 2.7.3

Comment: Whenever I am messing with unicode in python, I tend to refer back to: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/ it is the best explanation of how to deal with unicode in python 2.7 I have seen to date. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

If you concatenate strings with different encodings, python uses ascii as default to decode the string.
Which obviously is the wrong encoding in your case.

Your `aa` is a unicode `á`:

```
>>> print u'\xe1'
á
```

If you pass `aa` as unicode, it will work

```
>>> aa = u'\xe1'
>>> u'%s' % aa
u'\xe1'

>>> print u'%s' % aa
á
```

You cannot tread the `'\xe1'` as utf-8 because it's not valid in utf-8, therefore you cannot decode it.

```
>>> '\xe1'.decode('utf-8')
...

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Important part in the traceback is: `unexpected end of data`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
aa.decode('latin-1')
```

or

```
unicode('\xe1', 'latin-1')
```

'\xe1' (225 as an int) is not part of ascii, so, in order to transform your string into a unicode instance, you have to specify what encoding is used in the original string.

My examples assume your original string is in latin-1. Maybe you're using another encoding and you'll have to find out what it is.